# Informatica sorter transformation performance tunning related to cache allocation

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-cloud, bigdata

I am facing below warning for cache creation in session logs for sorter transformation in Informatica PowerCenter

> **Warning in session log.*
>   *Sorter Transformation [HIGHYIELDSPRDDELTA] required 2-pass sort (1-pass temp I/O: 23224320 bytes). You may try to set the cache size
>   to 30 MB or higher for 1-pass in-memory sort.*

On the web, people suggest to calculate the size of data in the file and hard code it in properties of sorter transformation but that is not feasible in our project and this approach will not be a dynamic approach if data size increases the mapping will give an error.

I want a dynamic solution to tune the performance of the mapping, in short, I want to reduce the time of cache file creation. please suggest any other method to tune the mapping

Any help will appreciate.

Comment: We don't help you but the community so I don't think anyone will call you on your phone. Just format this question better in order to be clear for people that want to anser it or that have the same problem and dlete your name/phone please

Comment: Hello Dear rakwaht, I think I explain it very well could you please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

This warning means : all given data  can't be sort at once as given cache/memory size is not enough. Data will be sorted in segments and combine later accordingly. You may face some performance issue some time. The best approach could be :

1. Read the sorted data if you are using any rational DB system provided your business logic not impacted.
2. Increase the cache memory size  (rather than auto) to process max possible data.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ankur for reply...I am using files to load data.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't set the sorter cache size to Auto. Please check and amend.

Have a look at following link

https://kb.informatica.com/h2l/HowTo%2520Library/1/0794-OptimizingSessionCachesInPowerCenter-H2L.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwio7dHIz4TWAhVGFMAKHVW_BOIQFgglMAA&usg=AFQjCNH7O6r7Tmdps2bgQll5qAjga-FgvQ

i.e. the two settings on the config tab dynamically control how much memory is shared between all transformations set to auto cache size

Maximum memory allowed for Auto Cache attributes
Maximum Percentage of Total Memory Allowed for Auto Memory Attributes

Comment: Hello Daniel....I set it to auto that's why the problem arises. Please suggest any other solution than Auto.